# Is it possible to fetch the user inviting your bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

When my Discord bot joins a guild, I want to send a private message to the member inviting the bot. I am using Discord.js.
Now, i know there is a `guildCreate` event i can use on the client, that fires when the bot joins a guild.

This event however, only provides the `Guild` the bot has been invited in.

I've seen multiple bots sending me private messages this way, so i know there must be a way. One could get the guild owner and send him private message, but there is a chance that the owner is not the one inviting the bot. And unfortunately, since i was always the owner when it happened, i can't say if it was this or not.

---

Is there a way to retrieve the `GuildMember`, or the `User` that invited the bot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires view audit log permissions for the bot:

```js
let logs = await guild.fetchAuditLogs()
logs = logs.entries.filter(e => e.action === "BOT_ADD")
let user = logs.find(l => l.target?.id === client.user.id)?.executor
//user is the inviter
```

Comment: I already said it needed the perms